# T2KFontFactory exception when JavaFX project starts through jar/jnpl

Tags: nullpointerexception, javafx-2

I have trouble when I trying to run my JavaFX project through executable jar file: "Exception while running Application". Running through jnpl file gives me more information: huge error message about java.lang.NullPointerException and T2KFontFactory (like "at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.resolveFontFiles(Unknown Source)", etc).

Also I received same exceptions when used WebView (but it worked).

I saw many posts about this problem in internet, but nobody knows solution. I'm using newest JavaFX 2.0.3, JRE version 1.7.0_03-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Windows 7. Thanks!

Edited:
I tested some JavaFX examples, they works well.

"body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 58302" so I will make a little cut of message:

```
Java Plug-in 10.4.1.99
Using JRE version 1.7.0_03-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\user
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.resolveFontFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.resolveWindowsFonts(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFullNameToFileMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFontResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.createFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.font(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.text.Font.font(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.ParsedValue.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_initPeer(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window$13.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.impl_showAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.DialogTemplate$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.DialogTemplate.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXPluginToolkit$Caller.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXPluginToolkit.callAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory.showErrorDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.ErrorPane$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.ErrorPane$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$6200(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.resolveFontFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.resolveWindowsFonts(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFullNameToFileMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFontResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.createFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.font(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.text.Font.font(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.ParsedValue.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_initPeer(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window$13.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.impl_showAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.DialogTemplate$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.DialogTemplate.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXPluginToolkit$Caller.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXPluginToolkit.callAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory.showErrorDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.ErrorPane$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.ErrorPane$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$6200(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.resolveFontFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.resolveWindowsFonts(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFullNameToFileMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFontResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.createFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.font(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.text.Font.font(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.ParsedValue.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_initPeer(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window$13.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.impl_showAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.DialogTemplate$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.DialogTemplate.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXPluginToolkit$Caller.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXPluginToolkit.callAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory.showErrorDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.ErrorPane$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.ErrorPane$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$6200(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.resolveFontFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.resolveWindowsFonts(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFullNameToFileMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFontResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.createFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.font(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.text.Font.font(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.ParsedValue.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_initPeer(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window$13.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.impl_showAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.DialogTemplate$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.DialogTemplate.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXPluginToolkit$Caller.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXPluginToolkit.callAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory.showErrorDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.ErrorPane$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.ErrorPane$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$6200(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.resolveFontFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.resolveWindowsFonts(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFullNameToFileMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFontResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.createFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.font(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.text.Font.font(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.ParsedValue.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_initPeer(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window$13.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.impl_showAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.DialogTemplate$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.DialogTemplate.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXPluginToolkit$Caller.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.FXPluginToolkit.callAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory.showErrorDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.FXUIFactory.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.ErrorPane$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.ui.ErrorPane$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$6200(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

Edited again:
Yes, my OS is russian) I tried 2.1 version, but it didn't help. After that I downloaded FX 2.2 (developer preview) and got new error message:

```
CacheEntry[file:/D:/Labs/Javal/JavafxApp/dist/lib/eclipselink-2.3.0.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Mon Apr 09 18:26:17 EEST 2012,length=6732665
CacheEntry[file:/D:/Labs/Javal/JavafxApp/dist/lib/javax.persistence-2.0.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Mon Apr 09 18:26:20 EEST 2012,length=143658
CacheEntry[file:/D:/Labs/Javal/JavafxApp/dist/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.19-bin.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Mon Apr 09 18:26:23 EEST 2012,length=831026
CacheEntry[file:/D:/Labs/Javal/JavafxApp/dist/JavafxApp.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Mon Apr 09 18:26:09 EEST 2012,length=9616796
```

I tried to fix that, but, I think that I'm misunderstanding the problem: I had mysql-connector-java-5.1.18, and changed it to newest: mysql-connector-java-5.1.19, but message about that didn't gone...

Comment: please, elaborate: does it happen with any JavaFX application? Do you have JavaFX runtime installed? And post whole exception.

Comment: Yes, I has all necessary software for JavaFX, the newest versions. I edited my question and I hope it will help to find solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have localized OS? It looks like http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18767

and this issue is fixed in FX 2.1 which you can get here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html

Comment: Thanks, but new error has appeared. I edited my first message.

Comment: did all error messages gone? Also try to clear your java cache (in Control Panel - Properties - Java) and make sure you've installed FX2.1 runtime, not only SDK/

Comment: As I said, FX2.1 didn't work for me, so I installed sdk and runtime of FX2.2. After that all exceptions about fonts gone, but appeared exceptions about my libraries and CacheEntry. So, after cache clearing I also can't start application, but now, when I'm pressing "Details" there are no text about exception. But if I run my project from Netbeans, and after that trying to run project through jnpl file - I receive exception about CacheEntry, as in my massage above...